# Sumif value is like a value in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In Google Sheets is it possible to sum values based on if part of the text matches?

Something like `=sumif(Road_Data_InfoX_914510!D:D,"FORMATION*",Road_Data_InfoX_914510!G:G)` - with this I get `#DIV/0!`

So in

[image]

I want to sum all the lengths where the item type starts with "FORMATION".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUMIF` can't return `#DIV/0!`

It should work fine

[image]

Comment: It was just because the first row had the title (text) so I had to use !G4:G